# redeclaration of function errors in C (microcontroller)

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, 68hc12

I am programming a HC6812 microcontroller and I need to use 2 functions in C to:

- switch off LEDs at port B
- Read switch input bits 0-4 on PTH (Port H)
- display switch value on 7 segment display at Port A.
- Light all LEDs on Port B for 0-31 seconds set by the switches.
- Finally turn off all LEDs at Port B.

My two functions are `Hexled` (to read the Hex switch input and display on 7 segment) and `wait`(to create a delay) .

When I compile the code I receive 4 errors:

'pointer expected' occurs twice in my `Hexled` function definition

'conflicting argument declarations for function `Hexled` '

'redeclaration error of `Hexled` '

I understand that with functions in C/C++ we need a function prototype, a function definition and in the main loop we call that function.  I do not understand what I have done wrong and would like to learn from it, I have tried researching numerous C programming web pages.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void wait(int);
void hexled (unsigned char,unsigned char);

unsigned char switchdata;
unsigned char a;
unsigned char b;
unsigned char mask;
unsigned char index;
unsigned char index1;

/******************* Declare the port addresses **********************/
unsigned char *PORTA = (unsigned char *)0x0000;
unsigned char *DDRA  = (unsigned char *)0x0002;  
unsigned char *PORTB = (unsigned char *)0x0001;
unsigned char *DDRB  = (unsigned char *)0x0003;
unsigned char *PTH   = (unsigned char *)0x0260;
unsigned char *DDRH  = (unsigned char *)0x0262;
unsigned char *PERH  = (unsigned char *)0x0264;

unsigned char LED_data[16] =     {0x3F,
                                  0x6,
                                  0x5B,
                                  0x4F,
                                  0x66,
                                  0x6D,
                                  0x7D,
                                  0x7,
                                  0x7F,
                                  0x6F,
                                  0x77,
                                  0x7C,
                                  0x39,
                                  0x5E,
                                  0x79,
                                  0x71}; // LED output




int main(void)
{
  /******************* Set up I/O ports********************************/    

*DDRH = 0x00;                   /* make Port H an input port */
*PERH = 0xFF;                   /* enable Port H */
*DDRA = 0xFF;                   /* make Port A an output port */
*DDRB = 0xFF;                   /* make Port B an output port */

  /******************* Main loop ***************************************/   


   *PORTB = 0xFF;

    mask = 0b00001111;

    switchdata = *PTH & mask;
    switchdata = *PORTA;

    index = (switchdata & 0b00010000);
    index1 = (switchdata | mask);

    hexled(index,index1);

    *PORTB = 0X00;

    wait(31);

    *PORTB = 0xFF;

    asm ("swi");

    return 0;
}



 // ***************************HEX FUNCTION**********************************
  void hexled(a,b) //* HEXLED function definition
  {                       
if (a)
     {
       *PORTA = switchdata [b] & 0b00010000;
     }
else
     {
       *PORTA = switchdata [b] | mask;
     }
  }


// ***************************DELAY FUNCTION************************************
 void wait(int seconds)  //*WAIT function defintion
   {
       int x,y,z;

       for (x=0; x<seconds; x++)
         {
           for (y=0; y<=100; y++)
             {
               for (z=0; z<=2000; z++);
             } 
         }  
   }
```

Comment: Please edit your post and fix your indention.

Comment: There is no language C/C++!

Answer (score 1):

Your function definition for `hexled` is missing parameter types - change:

```
void hexled(a,b) //* HEXLED function definition
```

to:

```
void hexled(unsigned char a, unsigned char b) //* HEXLED function definition
```

Also there is something weird with the way you are trying to use `switchdata` inside `hexled()`. It's a global `unsigned char` but you are trying to use it like it's an array or pointer when you do e.g.

```
   *PORTA = switchdata [b] & 0b00010000;
```

Maybe you can explain what you're actually trying to do here, and what `a` and `b` signify ? (Pro tip: using more meaningful parameter names might be a good idea.)

Comment: this has worked! Is it because in the function definition I need to show the types of the parameters? thank you

Comment: Yes, you got it write for `wait()` but somehow got it wrong for `hexled()`.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to declare it as an array though.

Comment: @Lundin: yes, I've just been updating the answer - OP seems to be trying to use `switchdata` in different ways at different points in the code.

Comment: @PaulR `switchdata` being my input to Port H, anded with a mask `0b00010000` so that only bits 0-4 are read, so bit 4 is acting like an on/off switch.

Comment: @user_1 You only need to mask once: when reading the port. `0b00010000`, apart from being invalid C, masks out bit 4 only. To mask out bits 0 to 4 you would have to write a mask as `0x1F`.

Answer (score 1):

Bugs/problems in your code:

- `/* enable Port H */` comment should say `enable pull-up Port H`.
- `switchdata = *PORTA;` it doesn't make sense to read a port which is set as output. Also it will not work on HC12: some ports have an input register where you can read the pin status, but PORTA is not one of them.
- You are using lots of global variables that should either have been declared locally in main() or as `static`.
- `LED_data` should be declared as `const` so that it gets allocated in flash.
- You are returning from main(), which doesn't make any sense in a freestanding implementation such as this. It will cause your program to crash.
- What is the software interrupt for and where is it handled? If left unhandled, your program will crash.
- The syntax for a function definition in C should be `void hexled (unsigned char a, unsigned char b)`.
- Neither `a` nor `b` are arrays and it doesn't make any sense to use any of them as arrays. All your code containing `[ ]` doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to achieve, bit masking?
- You seem to be reading switches but don't implement signal de-bouncing, so your program behavior related to switches will be random.
- Your wait function will potentially do nothing and get optimized out. At a minimum, you need to declare all loop iterator variables as `volatile`. It is however better practice to use on-chip timers. Check out the ECT or RTI timers.

Comment: I want to assign Port A to be whatever my switch input from Port H is anded with my mask.  I am getting very confused with all my code containing [ ], a lot of points you have mentioned are very helpful, but others I have very little idea what you are talking about. I have not much experience with C microcontrollers. I appreciate your points though.